# Make my laptop think it's on wifi when I'm hotspotting 3G from my phone

Tags: internet, wifi, skype

I teach lessons over Skype, but my internet isn't very good and after a lot of attempts to improve it I've come to the conclusion that my ISP just isn't able to provide me with reliable internet. I want to tether from my phone's 3G, but the problem is that Skype is banned over mobile connections in the country I'm in, so although the internet works fine when I hotspot, Skype just doesn't work.

I've looked into VPNs but I'm worried they will cause latency, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid, also they are quite expensive relative to the amount I'm earning from my lessons. I don't actually need Skype/my computer to think I'm in a different country, I just need them to think I'm on wifi in the country I'm in. Is there any software that could do this? Or any other way of achieving this?

I would be using a macbook and an iphone.

Thanks so much!!

Comment: if it's an ISP level ban (which probably is) then VPN is your only bet. Skype itself isn't blocking you out, as connecting a hotspot is no different than say connecting a wifi router as long as you choose otherwise (metered connections).